# Calculate the best middle vector with circle intersections

Tags: geometry, vectors, circles

I want to create in my game an "artificial inteligence" which is able to defend itself against ennemies. Let's see an example:

[image: Image exemple link]

A is the center of my IA, when an ennemie touch this IA, I calculate all the vector of the circle-circle intersections (which are represented in red) and then I calcultate all the middle vector (in blue)

Finally, I would like to know how to calculate the best defend vector in order to give my AI the best direction to avoid all enemies (represented in green).

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question unless you can specify what you mean by "the best defend vector" - in what sense is it "the best"? You may notice that, if you can formalize the notion of what counts here as "the best", you will yourself be half-way towards the solution.

Comment: what I mean by "best defense vector" is the vector that gets the AI ​​faster to no intersection between it and enemies. I don't know if calculating the greatest distance between each point of intersections, deducing the vector from it, taking the midpoint and calculating the vector passing between the center of my AI and this point would be a solution (optimized)

Comment: What if you search for the largest angle between red (or blue) lines?

Comment: Yeah it could be an idea but how calcultate the angle between two following lines like AK, AJ or AJ, AI but not AI, AK